# WP8.1 Panoramaitem Viewbox selected index

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, indexing, windows-phone-8.1

How can I get the selected index or item on WP8.1 from a ViewBox in a PanoramaItem? Here is my xaml and my c# code

**XAML**

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White">
                <!--Double wide Panorama with large image placeholders-->
                <Viewbox x:Name="Myitem" Height="800" Margin="0,-30,0,0" Width="912" >
                    <Border Height="800" Width="912">
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,177">
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,16,0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="1722">
                                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Border Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/Tiles/stib-pic0.gif"/>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,12,0,0">
                                    <Border Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,0,0" Tap="Border_Tap">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/Tiles/stib-pic1.gif"/>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/Tiles/stib-pic2.gif"/>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/Tiles/stib-pic3.gif"/>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/Tiles/stib-pic4.gif"/>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Viewbox>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

**C# Tap event**

```
private void Border_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Tapped!: " + "(number) item");
        }
```

I could find some tips on internet but they were all about `LongListSelector`

Answer (score 0):

For which control do you want to get the selected item?
If it is the Panorama, then you can give a name to the Panorama control containing the PanoramaItem and use [Panorama.SelectedIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectedindex(v=vs.105).aspx) property.

I don't any other control on the posted XAML that has a notion of a selected item...

Answer (score 0):

first of all you will have to provide header name of panorama item to easily get the selected header. and then call this snippet on panorama selection changed event.

```
var selectedItem = (PanoramaItem)(sender as Panorama).SelectedItem;
string item=selectedItem.Header.ToString();
```

Comment: As you see in the code above  (xaml and c# examples) I am not trying to get the selected items on selection changed event but on Tap event. The above sample you posted won't work.

Comment: Myitem item = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as Myitem;